# Protractor count elements and store the integer

Tags: javascript, count, integer, protractor

I want to count the elements in a list and then access the integer, not a `Promise` object. So starting with:

```
var questionList = questionContainer.all(by.className('someclass'));
```

If there are three child elements with that class, I want `console.log(questionList.count())` to output the integer `3`, not a `Promise` object. Is this even possible? Even if it is some operation on the `Promise`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`protractor` has the [`count()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) method available on [`ElementArrayFinder`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder):

```
expect(questionList.count()).toEqual(3);
```

Note that *`count()` returns a promise*, `expect()` is "patched" to resolve promises implicitly.

If you need the actual value to be, for instance, printed on the console - resolve the promise explicitly with `then()`:

```
questionList.count().then(function (count) {
    console.log(count);
});
```

Or, even simpler:

```
questionList.count().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

And, for instance, store the integer for using if statement?

```
questionList.count().then(function (count) {
     var res = count; 
});

if (res < 3) ...
```

It would be this way?

Comment: For posterity:

No, because by the time the promise resolves, the conditional `if (res < 3)` would have been executed with the `res` being `undefined`.

In your case, you should better place it on the inside of the promise, together with the variable assignment.